# Structures on the Far Side of the Moon?

Tags: the-moon

I downloaded an image of the far side of the moon using Google Earth. It is an area to the North West of the Mare Moscoviense (lat 27.3$^{\circ}$ lon 147.9$^{\circ}$)

What are the dot-like structures inside the right edge of the crater?

There are also three dots inside the small crater to the South East of the large crater making an equilateral triangle.

Are they real or are they photo artifacts?

I couldn't find any similar dot-like structures on the near side of the moon.

[image]

Some larger linear structures in craters

[image]

Comment: There are dots all over the place at the edges of shaded areas. They are probably just boulders poking up into the sunlight. No need for imaging artefacts or alien bases to explain them away.

Comment: It's strange I don't see any such dots on images from the near side of the moon.

Comment: I've searched around the inside edges of craters on the near side of the moon at a scale of 1km and I can't see any dot-like structures.

Comment: However I do find a lot of dot-like structures on the inside of craters around the Mare Moscoviense on the far side of the moon at a scale of 1km.

Comment: These are artifacts of how Google shifts between different zoom levels and applies an (incorrect) lighting model to its textured 3D model of the Moon. This is explained here https://www.metabunk.org/threads/debunked-alien-base-on-the-moon-triangle-of-dots-photo-artifact.2965/

Comment: @PeterErwin If you feel that's the answer then please post an answer with a brief summary of the contents of the link so as to avoid a link-only answer.

Answer (score 4):

These are artefacts of how Google shifts between different zoom levels and applies an (incorrect) lighting model to its textured 3D model of the Moon. This is explained here:

https://www.metabunk.org/threads/debunked-alien-base-on-the-moon-triangle-of-dots-photo-artifact.2965/

As Mick West says in the above https://www.metabunk.org thread, you can set Global Maps->Colorized Terrain on Google Earth to confirm that these pixels are artefacts. See this photo for example:

[image]

Comment: Answers shouldn't be written in reply to comments, so I've removed the @tags (which don't work in answers anyway)